# Integrating spree commerce with paypal offsite redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree, spree-paypal-express

I am trying to integrate PayPal with a Spree Commerce store. On the payments screen, when I select PayPal, it asks me to enter the credit card details instead of redirecting to PayPal website.

How do I redirect my users to paypal website for the payment?

Answer (score 1):

What you're after is the [better spree paypal express extension](https://github.com/spree-contrib/better_spree_paypal_express). And then you'll want to add a new gateway and select `Spree::Gateway::PayPalExpress` as the provider.